# How to dynamically correct a TextBox's Input Validation as soon as it loses focus?

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, windows-phone-8, textbox

I am confused at my if statement that says if the textbox is null, has whitespace, empty string, contains specific characters or has regex characters, it will validate as correct. But instead, it validates as incorrect when I input text before losing focus as required by if-statement to pass. What am I doing wrong here? I notice adding an if(!(..)) will make it work the opposite way but that isn't correct logic and I'm confused.

```
    // firstNameTB Textbox to dynamically check validation
    private void firstNameTB_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstNameTB.Text) || firstNameTB.Text == "" || firstNameTB.Text.Contains("") || !Regex.IsMatch(firstNameTB.Text, @"^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+$"))
        {
            firstNameTBL.Text = "First Name: *";
            firstNameTBL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            firstNameTBL.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        else
        {
            // set back to default layout
            this.firstNameTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
            this.firstNameTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty);
            this.firstNameTBL.Text = "First Name:";
        }
    }

    // lastNameTB Textbox to dynamically check validation
    private void lastNameTB_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastNameTB.Text) || lastNameTB.Text == "" || lastNameTB.Text.Contains("") || !Regex.IsMatch(lastNameTB.Text, @"^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+$"))
        {
            lastNameTBL.Text = "Last Name: *";
            lastNameTBL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            lastNameTBL.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        else
        {
            // set back to default layout
            this.lastNameTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
            this.lastNameTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty);
            this.lastNameTBL.Text = "Last Name:";
        }
    }

    // emailAddressTB Textbox to dynamically check validation
    private void emailAddressTB_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailAddressTB.Text) || emailAddressTB.Text == "" || !(emailAddressTB.Text.Contains("@") && emailAddressTB.Text.Contains(".")))
        {
            emailAddressTBL.Text = "Email Address: *";
            emailAddressTBL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            emailAddressTBL.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        else
        {
            // set back to default layout
            this.emailAddressTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty);
            this.emailAddressTBL.ClearValue(TextBlock.FontWeightProperty);
            this.emailAddressTBL.Text = "Email Address:";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the ckecks to see whether textboxes contain empty strings e.g.:

```
... || lastNameTB.Text.Contains("") || ...
... || firstNameTB.Text.Contains("") || ...
```

Because these always evaluate to `true` - you get the behavior you described.
To fix this - simply remove these conditions from the if statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Empty` to check the String is empty or not:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastNameTB.Text) ||
    lastNameTB.Text == String.Empty || 
    !Regex.IsMatch(lastNameTB.Text, @"^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+$"))
{

}
```